# Make another table with ID and distinct errors between two rows containing same id - SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has two columns ("time_stamp" and "message").

Example dataframe:

```
Time_stamp                   Message
2020-12-01 05:28:34:215      some text1 ID: 1
2020-12-01 05:28:40:210      some text2 error: A
2020-12-01 05:28:40:220      some text3 error: B
2020-12-01 05:28:41:203      some text4 error: A
2020-12-01 05:30:43:201      some text5 ID: 1
2020-12-01 05:32:50:215      some text6 ID: 2
2020-12-01 05:32:50:220      some text7 error: A
2020-12-01 05:48:51:220      some text8 error: C
2020-12-01 05:48:52:203      some text9 error: B
2020-12-01 05:51:53:201      some text10 ID: 2
```

I want to make another dataframe with ID and distinct errors between two rows containing same id.

Expected output:

Example table:

```
ID          Error
1           A
1           B
2           A
2           C
2           B
```

Thanks

Comment: I am basically using Apache spark on databricks and having a spark dataframe. SQL query can be run on this dataframe. So mysql query can be easilt run for spark dataframe. using spark.sql

Comment: Spark SQL is not the same as MySQL. You cannot run MySQL queries on Spark dataframes. Those queries are called Spark SQL queries.

Comment: Oh I see. thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. The code groups by ID, collects the error messages and gets the earliest error message for each distinct error message. Time order is maintained.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Time_stamp',
    F.to_timestamp('Time_stamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS')
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.regexp_extract('Message', 'ID: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 1)
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.last(F.when(F.col('ID') != '', F.col('ID')), True).over(Window.orderBy('Time_stamp'))
).filter(
    F.col('message').rlike('error')
).withColumn(
    'Message',
    F.regexp_extract('Message', 'error: (.*)', 1)
).groupBy('ID').agg(
    F.collect_set(F.array('Message', 'Time_stamp')).alias('Message')
).select(
    'ID',
    F.explode('Message').alias('Message')
).selectExpr(
    'ID',
    'Message[0] as error',
    'Message[1] as Time_stamp'
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('ID', 'error').orderBy('Time_stamp'))
).filter('rn = 1').orderBy('Time_stamp').select('ID', 'error')
```

Comment: Thank you. let me understand the code and implement it in actual data. Actual data is little bit different, so need to modify it accordingly. Shall I update my data to match with actual data?

Comment: @Dataholic the code should also work without any modifications.

Comment: I ran the code. The output dataframe contains two columns (ID and error), but those columns are blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225889/discussion-between-dataholic-and-mck).